# Faster alternative to ImageCorrespondingPoints?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to use `ImageCorrespondingPoints` to register frames in a video sequence. Computational speed is an important consideration for the application I am working on, so I have been trying this out using the various feature descriptors built into Mathematica.

What I am confused about is why `ORB` and `AKAZE` methods are performing significantly slower than `SURF` or `KAZE`.

The code here is a minimal example that illustrates what I am observing:

```
images = ImageTrim[ExampleData[{"AerialImage", 
 "Earth"}], {{{1, 1}, {300, 300}}, {{101, 101}, {400, 400}}}];

(* ImageKeypoints Benchmark *)

keypointMethod = {"FAST", "ORB", "AKAZE", "SURF", "KAZE", "BRISK"};
properties = {"Position", "Strength", "Scale", "Orientation"};

timing = (RepeatedTiming[
  ImageKeypoints[RandomChoice[images], properties, 
   Method -> #, MaxFeatures -> 100], 1][[1]] &) /@ keypointMethod;

BarChart[timing, ChartLabels -> keypointMethod, PlotLabel -> "Computation speed (seconds)"]
```

[image: ImageKeypoints Benchmark]

```
(* ImageCorrespondingPoints Benchmark *)

timing2 = (RepeatedTiming[
  ImageCorrespondingPoints[images[[1]], images[[2]], Method -> #, 
   MaxFeatures -> 100], 3][[1]] &) /@ Rest[keypointMethod];

BarChart[timing2, ChartLabels -> Rest[keypointMethod], PlotLabel -> "Computation speed (seconds)"]
```

[image: ImageCorrespondingPoints Benchmark]

I know that `ImageCorrespondingPoints` is doing some additional computation to register the key points after the descriptors are extracted, but I don't understand why there is such a large computational difference in doing that for `ORB` vs `KAZE`, for example.

Does anyone have any insight into what is going on here? Perhaps the Mathematica implementation is just not well maintained and poorly optimized?

If anyone has an idea of how one might go about implementing their own `ImageCorrespondingPoints` function that would be helpful.